# Why do the "Successfully updated" notifications disappear?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, notifications

I noticed a weird behavior when updating applications with the newer Gingerbread (2.3.5?) and now Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.3) builds. It might also be the case with other versions, but I have not seen it with 2.3.3 and lower on my Nexus S. **EDIT:** As Chahk pointed out below, it might not be related to the Android OS version but rather to a recent change in the Market App.

I have a lot of apps installed (currently around 160). Now when I go to the Market after a couple of days there are usually several updates available (say 10).

**The way it used to be:**
I hit "Update 10" and let the device download and install the updates. After that I had 10 separate "Successfully updated" notification messages in my notification window.

**The way it is now:**
During update installations the "Successfully updated" notifications seem to randomly disappear or not show up at all.

Why is that? Is there a way to get the old behavior back? Otherwise there would be no way to tell which apps have received updates without first making a list of all the apps prior to pressing "Update".

Comment: Don't you get the "10 applications successfully updated" type notification, I thought that was standard from Honeycomb onwards, rather than notifying you about every app?

Comment: I don't think this is limited to Android OS version, as I'm seeing the same behavior on both my Atrix 4G that's running stock Gingerbread 2.3.4, and Galaxy Tab rinning a beta ICS build.  This change must have been introduced in the recent version of the Market app itself.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I do not get this type of notification. Also if possible, I want the old behavior back (separate notification for each updated app).

Chahk: It might in fact be related to the Market app. Thanks for your comment, updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new 'feature' in market version 3.x, which got pushed out some time last year to gingerbread devices. If you have a rooted phone and really want the old behaviour back, uninstall the 'market updater' and install android market 2.3.6 Here's an apk of it from my dropbox https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2302883/com.android.vending-5cbc09eeba96ab104fe111e029312f42.apk.gz